# Upgrade Ubuntu Mate 20.04 with losing customizations

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I was told I would not lose my customizations and icons when upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04.

But at the "installation type screen", there is no pick that does not erase everything except for the side by side installation.

Is there a way to not lose my customizations and installed programs?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I upgrade Ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04 without losing packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229842/how-can-i-upgrade-ubuntu-from-19-10-to-20-04-without-losing-packages)

Comment: @N0rbert I have done this. The icons on my desktop disappeared and a spinning circle is showing .This might work: open the update center in Ubuntu and then check for updates. If it asks you if you want to update to 20.04 select yes and you shouldn't (I'm not sure) lose any packages (although some packages might become obsolete).

Comment: Is there a way to tell if the update is occurring?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm sorry but it's unclear (at least to me) what version you are attempting to upgrade from. Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and then [edit] your question to provide further clarity. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

I used this procedure to do the upgrade.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/